# Animate a View to give scrolling animation like traditional volume button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a volume button like this which need to be animated to give scrolling effect and increase volume of device.

[image: Volume Button]

I know how to increase volume of iPhone device but unable to find out how to give animation and pass values accordingly to the API (increasing volume or decreasing volume). Whether a user is scrolling up or down.

Comment: swift or Objective-C?

Comment: @neuronical - Swift!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the image view displaying the volume thingo. Then assign a method to handle the

```
func volumeViewDidPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view)
    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        initialY = translation.y
    }
    else {
        if translation.y <= initialY {
            //Their finger is moving up towards 0 or the same
            //Calculate step - update image/volume
        }
        else {
            //Their finger is moving down towards height
            //Calculate step - update image/volume
        }
    }
}
```

Then based on the value, offset/steps you are doing you can trigger your volume changes.

Comment: Thanks... Will let you know if i have more questions